# Positivity of an operator defined on $C(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $X'$ be non empty open and closed subset of $X$. Let $C(X)$ be the the space of complex valued continuous functions on $X$. Define $\chi: X \to \{0,1\}$ as $\chi(t)=1$ iff $t \in X'$. Define $T_{f,f }: C(X) \to C(X)$ as $T_{f,f}(g)=(2\chi-1) g\overline f f$

> $T_{f,f} \geq 0$ iff $f=u \chi$ for some $u \in C(X)$.

Can someone explain the forward part? Converse is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $X'$ is open and closed, the function   $g=1-\chi$ is continuous on $X.$  We have $g\ge 0$ and
$$T_{f,f}(g)= (2\chi-1)(1-\chi)|f|^2=-(1-\chi)|f|^2\le 0$$
If $T_{f,f}\ge 0,$ then $(1-\chi)|f|^2=0.$ Thus $(1-\chi)f=0,$ i.e. $f=f\chi.$

Comment: How do you conclude $(1- \chi)f=0$ ?

Comment: $|(1-\chi)|f|^2=|(1-\chi)f|^2$

Comment: Obviously, thank you so much!